# Parsing Date dynamically in a jTable

Tags: java, swing, date, jtable

I have a jTable with four columns. the first column holds some code of members, second column holds their admission date and third column holds their validation expiry date. I've to remove the rows from the column if the expiry date is more than 10 days from the system date.

I'm writing the code something like this:

```
    public void expire(){

    try{
    DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel) empTbl.getModel();
    int col=2;
    int rows = empTbl.getRowCount();
    for(int row=0; row<=rows; row++){

     SimpleDateFormat formater = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
     Calendar currentDate = Calendar.getInstance();
     String d = formater.format(currentDate.getTime());
     Date haatdinPisorTarikh = (Date)formater.parse(d);   

     String expdate = (String)empTbl.getValueAt(row, col);
     Date expire=(Date)formater.parse(expdate);
     Calendar expireDate = Calendar.getInstance();
     expireDate.add(Calendar.DATE, -10);

     if(expireDate.after(haatdinPisorTarikh)){
     model.removeRow(row);
     }
     }

      }catch(ParseException ex){}
       }
```

This method is not working. Where am I doing mistake ?
Please help...

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The most significant issue is in your loop (obviously)...

```
int rows = empTbl.getRowCount(); // <-- Get row count, good...
for(int row=0; row<=rows; row++){
    // Make your calculations...
    if(expireDate.after(haatdinPisorTarikh)){
        model.removeRow(row);
        // Uh-oh, the row count has changed
        // Also, the row index is no longer valid!!
    }
}
```

What you should do, is place some kind of row identifier into a `java.util.List` (don't use the row index, you'll run into the same problems), adding each row you want to delete to it and after you've completed the scan of the model, iterate over the "remove" list, looking up each rows index by the identifier and remove it.

Otherwise you could just use a [table filter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#sorting) which I think would significantly easier...

Answer (score 2):

You can organize the for starting from the end.

```
int rows = empTbl.getRowCount(); 
for(int row=rows-1; row>=0; row--) {
    //delete from model won't harm your row indexes.
}
```