# JTable not updating from a SwingWorker thread

Tags: java, swing, jtable, swingworker, jide

I currently have a JTable that is populated with a series of data that forms the basis of a import screen. When I have finished selecting which updates I want or do not want, I press on the Apply button and the updates are applied successfully but the JTable does not fully update.

This is the code for the method that deals with applying the changes:

```
private void doProcessChanges() {
    ChangeProcessor cp = new ChangeProcessor();
    final List<Integer> rowsToRemove = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    BeanTableModel<UpdateModel> model = (BeanTableModel<UpdateModel>) table.getModel();

    for (int i=0; i<model.getRowCount(); i++) {
        UpdateRow ur = mode.getObject(i);
        if (ur.isAccepted() <> ChangeAcceptance.NO_ACTION) {
           cp.processChange(ur);
           rowsToRemove.add(i);
        }
    }

   SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            for (int row : rowsToRemove) {
                model.removeObject(row);
                model.fireTableDataChanged();
            }
    }
);
}
```

The method is called from within a SwingWorker thread as below:

```
 SwingWorker<Object, Object> worker = new SwingWorker<Object, Object>() {

                    @Override
                    protected Object doInBackground() throws Exception {
                        doProcessChanges();
                        return null;
                    }

                    @Override
                    protected void done() {
                        try {
                            get();
                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        } catch (ExecutionException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                };
```

I do not get any exceptions from executing this so I am I doing anything wrong?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please edit your question to include an [sscce](http://sscce.org/) that shows your implementation of `publish()` and `process()`.

Comment: I do not currently have an implementation of the `publish()` or `process()` methods.

Comment: `ur.isAccepted() <> ChangeAcceptance.NO_ACTION` what <> means ?

Comment: this question is about debugging, with real data, not like as question to forum, Jide couldn't be important if you missing data, see [this thread about delete row(s) from model](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14454928/714968), hmmm are those models generated on fly linked to visible JTable, I'd be doubt ...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your fragment shows incorrect synchronization. In particular, you access [`BeanTableModel`](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/11/27/bean-table-model/), a subclass of `AbstractTableModel`, from the background thread. Instead, pass the `List<Integer> rowsToRemove` to your worker in its constructor.

Addendum: Instead of `invokeLater()`, you can update the `TableModel` in your implementation of `process()`, which executes on the EDT. Also, you shouldn't have to `fireTableDataChanged()`, which "Notifies all listeners that *all* cell values in the table's rows may have changed." The `removeObject()` implementation should fire the *least* pervasive event required to effect the change.